# Eclipse with Red Hat Codeready (Fuse Integration) developing for Wildfly Application Server

Tags: eclipse, apache-camel, wildfly, jbossfuse

I'm a little bit con-fuse-d with Red Hats Fuse tooling.
Here's what I'd like to do: Design Camel Routes with Eclipse (2020-03) and then deploy them to a Wildfly server (16 or 18) with the [wildfly-camel](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel) patch applied.

This generally works, BUT:

1. The version of Fuse in the tool is 7.6 (latest) with a highest available camel version of **2.21**(!) which is very old. The wildfly-camel patch already supports camel 3.0. on wildfly 18. Question: Is it possible to "update" Fuse Tooling within Codeready to newer versions of camel?
2. Fuse itself supports lots of camel components / connectors as can be seen [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/connectors/). But not all of them are available in Codeready. Plus that some of the components state to be compatible for example with camel versions greater than 2.8. Question: How to add these components to the visual design UI of Fuse Tooling?

I fear that it all is a matter of the outdated version of camel, but I want to be sure that I didn't miss anything. To those who know: Are there any plans of updating the Tool for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuse Tools for Eclipse is primarily designed to work with [Red Hat Fuse](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-fuse/) which, as you rightly point out, aligns to [specific supported versions of Apache Camel](https://access.redhat.com/articles/348423).

But, you should be able to create your own Wildfly-Camel project (or [use one of the examples](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel-examples)) and still use the graphical route editor to add newer components. You'll need to drag a Generic component from the palette and then untick *Show only palette components*, which should show you all the components available, including ones from newer releases of Camel:

[image]

Just tested this with:

- Fresh install of Eclipse 2020.03 with [Fuse Tools](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/) installed
- Latest clone of [Wildfly-Camel-Examples](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel-examples) repo
- Opening camel-jms-spring project in Eclipse
- Opening src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/camel-context.xml with the graphical route editor
- Dragging a new Generic component, XSLT-Saxon, from the Palette.